# How can I fill in missing rows for monthly time series data?

Tags: r, data.table, time-series, tidyverse, lubridate

Here's the dput of my data:

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(8596, 8631, 8659, 8687, 8733, 
8743, 8796, 8806, 8853, 8880, 8908, 8932, 8971, 8999, 9027, 9069, 
9097, 9111, 9160, 9188, 9212, 9230, 9279, 9309, 9328, 9363, 9391, 
9434, 9449, 9482, 9519, 9541, 9580, 9610, 9643, 9672, 9708, 9736, 
9764, 9799, 9827, 9850, 9890, 9920, 9947, 9975, 10007, 10038, 
10072, 10100, 10122, 10163, 10191, 10213, 10254, 10282, 10310, 
10345, 10354, 10385, 10418, 10469, 10497, 10528, 10556, 10570, 
10612, 10641, 10668, 10710, 10742, 10759, 10802, 10830, 10858, 
10893, 10914, 10947, 10984, 11010, 11038, 11066, 11096, 11135, 
11164, 11193, 11229, 11257, 11285, 11313, 11346, 11374, 11411, 
11435, 11467, 11502, 11514, 11565, 11592, 11621, 11649, 11677, 
11718, 11746, 11776, 11797, 11838, 11867, 11894, 11923, 11951, 
11979, 12021, 12035, 12077, 12105, 12133, 12160, 12189, 12231, 
12259, 12273, 12315, 12356, 12385, 12399, 12441, 12472, 12497, 
12538, 12553, 12591, 12630, 12658, 12686, 12714, 12742, 12770, 
12804, 12832, 12860, 12903, 12917, 12938, 12986, 13015, 13056, 
13085, 13116, 13139, 13169, 13204, 13232, 13260, 13288, 13301, 
13357, 13385, 13414, 13442, 13470, 13498, 13533, 13561, 13603, 
13631, 13658, 13694, 13722, 13750, 13778, 13805, 13846, 13862, 
13896, 13925, 13967, 13995, 14009, 14050, 14078, 14121, 14149, 
14177, 14205, 14233, 14268, 14296, 14323, 14352, 14380, 14449, 
14474, 14506, 14548, 14575, 14590, 14618, 14661, 14688, 14729, 
14758, 14761, 14821, 14849, 14877, 14905, 14933, 14961, 14995, 
15024, 15038, 15093, 15121, 15135, 15185, 15212, 15241, 15269, 
15297, 15325, 15360, 15387, 15430, 15458, 15485, 15513, 15542, 
15583, 15611, 15639, 15667, 15696, 15731, 15745, 15786, 15815, 
15842, 15917, 15945, 15966, 16001, 16030, 16076, 16129, 16143, 
16184, 16276, 16303, 16343, 16374, 16400, 16417, 16455, 16482, 
16525, 16553, 16585, 16612, 16646, 16678, 16706, 16729, 16752, 
16777, 16819, 16860, 16891, 16916, 16925, 16976, 17002, 17042, 
17072, 17100, 17120, 17141, 17178, 17224, 17245, 17261, 17304, 
17330, 17373, 17401, 17459, 17488, 17512, 17548, 17581, 17598, 
17631), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date", class = "Date"), AverageTemp = c(16.5027083333333, 
17.325, 17.1888888888889, 15.8277777777778, 16.6583333333333, 
17.3333333333333, 16.64375, 17.1133333333333, 17.895119047619, 
18.5694444444444, 18.8222222222222, 17.4305555555556, 17.6555555555556, 
17.025, 17.3222222222222, 17.2770833333333, 17.4805555555556, 
16.9708333333333, 17.9666666666667, 17.1222222222222, 18.0166666666667, 
17.25, 18.1875, 17.6577777777778, 16.6541666666667, 17.1083333333333, 
16.4666666666667, 17.5972756410256, 17.2, 17.4444444444444, 16.95, 
17.7, 17.9222222222222, 18.4875, 17.8229166666667, 16.9166666666667, 
16.7083333333333, 17.1666666666667, 17.3111111111111, 18.2333333333333, 
16.6277777777778, 17.5875, 17.3833333333333, 17.4638888888889, 
17.725, 18.1388888888889, 17.7001111111111, 17.7222222222222, 
17.2041666666667, 17.8255952380952, 17.1833333333333, 17.8103070175439, 
17.8194444444444, 17.952, 18.158412414966, 18.4910714285714, 
18.3488562091503, 19.1341830065359, 18.45, 18.9107142857143, 
17.2275, 19.0828761904762, 18.1599701591512, 18.965739220457, 
18.6720606060606, 18.8786057692308, 18.602656449553, 18.6327347883598, 
19.2925198412698, 20.1952463624339, 18.8900384227765, 18.0934444444444, 
18.0554871794872, 17.8405270655271, 17.5540598290598, 17.454122110648, 
17.5764155982906, 16.9989942528736, 16.4252032967033, 16.5388571428571, 
17.0108695652174, 17.7725308641975, 18.4252564102564, 17.2278899240856, 
17.3102091315453, 17.3627204585538, 17.280641025641, 17.3746616809117, 
17.3014601139601, 17.2238271604938, 16.379012345679, 16.6044444444444, 
17.624415954416, 18.4023148148148, 18.0341435185185, 17.3016666666667, 
17.8204861111111, 17.827264957265, 17.2772467320261, 17.8786954365079, 
17.84375, 17.1732638888889, 16.9219907407407, 17.3826388888889, 
17.7413333333333, 18.4948412698413, 18.2363425925926, 17.3282057823129, 
17.5083333333333, 17.414898989899, 16.9453125, 17.4988095238095, 
17.6704012345679, 18.1333333333333, 18.11875, 17.4805555555556, 
17.4271367521368, 17.9006944444444, 17.9818181818182, 17.3125, 
16.73625, 17.2666666666667, 17.4279340277778, 17.8584444444444, 
17.2966666666667, 17.1, 18.3420833333333, 18.5814285714286, 17.6430555555556, 
18.2307122507123, 18.0830687830688, 16.7563492063492, 16.9055555555556, 
17.0090277777778, 17.3863095238095, 16.9139880952381, 16.7479166666667, 
17.0888888888889, 17.7648148148148, 18.2277777777778, 19.3694444444444, 
17.7064021164021, 18.7371527777778, 17.94375, 17.9416666666667, 
17.8736111111111, 18.5354166666667, 18.1919444444444, 18.2555555555556, 
17.7704365079365, 17.3509259259259, 17.3931216931217, 18.3355923202614, 
17.9180555555556, 18.2104166666667, 18.0171121593291, 17.6840277777778, 
17.5509259259259, 16.9631313131313, 17.4478070175439, 17.6916666666667, 
17.6143376068376, 18.7415656565657, 19.0048611111111, 18.285462962963, 
18.3816964285714, 18.2041310541311, 17.2343518518519, 17.2149382716049, 
17.3684027777778, 17.5229861111111, 16.8517857142857, 19.0929141414141, 
19.300404040404, 18.735, 17.9280277777778, 18.4470274170274, 
19.0686597406425, 18.325, 18.5, 18.4388888888889, 18.7291666666667, 
18.3708333333333, 18.0234918630752, 19.4925980392157, 19.2101488095238, 
19.3890625, 18.5150793650794, 19.1944444444444, 19.0815277777778, 
19.5192658730159, 17.2212418300654, 17.8081168831169, 18.2517361111111, 
17.7775555555556, 18.012962962963, 17.0347222222222, 16.5888888888889, 
18.8123101604278, 18.9187091503268, 19.0161111111111, 19.2625, 
20.875, 18.8092592592593, 18.6526515151515, 18.9083333333333, 
18.9835227272727, 18.1829292929293, 17.9060606060606, 17.7835227272727, 
17.8237719298246, 19.7386363636364, 18.4961051693405, 18.5332727272727, 
18.3787878787879, 18.5134199134199, 17.8098930481283, 18.4179292929293, 
17.230303030303, 18.9035064935065, 17.8935897435897, 17.6211966604824, 
17.9238095238095, 18.8382886904762, 19.42625, 18.6395833333333, 
18.0652777777778, 19.3354166666667, 18.75359375, 17.951123043623, 
17.6063068181818, 17.828022875817, 17.5528846153846, 18.5647727272727, 
19.0318181818182, 19.1659090909091, 18.8997564935065, 19.1301136363636, 
18.1705882352941, 17.1361570247934, 18.6090909090909, 18.1429951690821, 
17.8829545454545, 18.3387983091787, 18.41875, 19.7, 20.2508333333333, 
17.6387426900585, 18.1770897832817, 17.5400297619048, 17.7547246376812, 
17.246412037037, 17.0846153846154, 17.7060185185185, 18.325, 
18.5408333333333, 19.4251587301587, 18.3706018518519, 17.917, 
17.91, 18.6451388888889, 18.29375, 17.2316666666667, 18.7189393939394, 
18.1669193548387, 18.367297979798, 17.7043055555556, 18.1879520697168, 
19.12, 20.425, 18.6663888888889, 17.5108796296296, 18.1883333333333, 
18.3060049019608, 18.32625, 18.2861111111111, 18.0375, 17.3445175438596, 
18.6451058201058, 18.97875, 19.4583333333333, 18.2597222222222, 
19.9197222222222, 18.2342307692308, 18.7666666666667, 19.8277777777778, 
17.6464285714286, 18.690873015873, 18.4520833333333, 19.8696428571429, 
19.9833333333333, 18.2416666666667)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-292L))
```

My data is in YYYY-MM-DD format and is monthly data. Right now, there's missing data for a few months (e.g. 2017-09, 2014-05, 2014-06, 2013-12), but they are not specified in the data frame. How do I create a new row for possible missing months across my entire dataset? Since my dataset has two columns, the other column besides the date column should have an NA value specified for the new missing month row. I'm looking for a tidyverse, lubridate, or data.table solution.

Comment: Hi @arg0naut, unfortunately this didn't work. It turned most of the values of my second column into NAs, removing values that were fine.

Comment: `join` to full sequence of dates, if you want last observations to be carried to newly added rows then `self rolling join`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::complete` for this, but you have the additional wrinkle that you have dates on different days in each month. First then you need to make a column to count months on, which we can do with the `day(x) <-` setter from `lubridate`.

Here's an example using the provided data truncated to 2014 for conciseness. Note that you should use `seq.Date` to specify the full range of dates that you want to be included in the month column, and you also will have `NA`s in the `date` column. (you can replace with the first of the month if you want)

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

tbl <- structure(list(date = structure(c(16076, 16129, 16143, 16184, 16276, 16303, 16343, 16374, 16400, 16417), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date", class = "Date"), AverageTemp = c(18.3387983091787, 18.41875, 19.7, 20.2508333333333, 17.6387426900585, 18.1770897832817, 17.5400297619048, 17.7547246376812, 17.246412037037, 17.0846153846154)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

tbl %>%
  mutate(month = date %>% `day<-`(1)) %>%
  complete(month = seq.Date(min(month), max(month), by = "month"))
#> # A tibble: 12 x 3
#>    month      date       AverageTemp
#>    <date>     <date>           <dbl>
#>  1 2014-01-01 2014-01-06        18.3
#>  2 2014-02-01 2014-02-28        18.4
#>  3 2014-03-01 2014-03-14        19.7
#>  4 2014-04-01 2014-04-24        20.3
#>  5 2014-05-01 NA                NA  
#>  6 2014-06-01 NA                NA  
#>  7 2014-07-01 2014-07-25        17.6
#>  8 2014-08-01 2014-08-21        18.2
#>  9 2014-09-01 2014-09-30        17.5
#> 10 2014-10-01 2014-10-31        17.8
#> 11 2014-11-01 2014-11-26        17.2
#> 12 2014-12-01 2014-12-13        17.1
```

As an alternative, you can instead just get the year and month components and use `complete` on the combination of the two:

```r
tbl %>%
  mutate(year = year(date), month = month(date)) %>%
  complete(year = min(year):max(year), month = 1:12)
#> # A tibble: 12 x 4
#>     year month date       AverageTemp
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <date>           <dbl>
#>  1  2014     1 2014-01-06        18.3
#>  2  2014     2 2014-02-28        18.4
#>  3  2014     3 2014-03-14        19.7
#>  4  2014     4 2014-04-24        20.3
#>  5  2014     5 NA                NA  
#>  6  2014     6 NA                NA  
#>  7  2014     7 2014-07-25        17.6
#>  8  2014     8 2014-08-21        18.2
#>  9  2014     9 2014-09-30        17.5
#> 10  2014    10 2014-10-31        17.8
#> 11  2014    11 2014-11-26        17.2
#> 12  2014    12 2014-12-13        17.1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>